# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')

Tags: react-native, google-distancematrix-api, distance-matrix, react-google-maps-api

I am trying to use the DistanceMatrixService from @react-google-maps/api. One of the required parameters is the 'travelMode'. However, when I tried setting 'travelMode' to 'DRIVING', it shows the following!

[image]

I tried doing
travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
but it also throws a type error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')

[image]

Here is a snippet of my code where I call the Distance Matrix Service.

[image: snippet]

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Updated code snippet @LalitFauzdar.

Comment: You're facing Type issue as your screenshot and code snipped shows: `Type "Driving" is not assignable to Type "TravelMode"`. For this, check this typescript example on [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix#maps_distance_matrix-typescript).

Comment: @LalitFauzdar I tried using the "google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING" however I guess the 'window.google' does not exist. Any idea on how to work around this?